# Embedding Youtube videos for non JavaScript users

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, accessibility

I am trying to embed youtube on my site, but need it to work for users without JavaScript.  I am using the standard embed code they supply, with the iframe.  But it seems like Youtube now requires JavaScript because they don't load with it disabled. And if you go to their own site with JavaScript disabled none of the videos load.  Is there no way around this?  Seems kind of crazy to not supply a fully accessible alternative!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should try something like this. Remember this is a sample height and width. Hope this helped

`<embed width="420" height="345"
src="URL OF THE YOUTUBE VIDEO"
type="application/x-shockwave-flash">`